# Why does Bootstrap 5's getOrCreateInstance() method for collapsibles immediately toggle the element?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I've not had to work with the Collapse feature in Bootstrap 5 until today and I strongly dislike it!

If I have a simple setup with a collapsible element - hidden initially - and a button to toggle its visibility, like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="toggleDetails">Show Details</button>
<div class="collapse border mt-2 p-2" id="details">
    Here is some information.
</div>
```

and some Javascript like this:

```
const details = document.getElementById("details");
const detailsCollapse = bootstrap.Collapse.getOrCreateInstance(details);

const btn = document.getElementById("toggleDetails");
btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    detailsCollapse.toggle();
});
```

why does the `getOrCreateInstance` toggle the collapsible element's visibility? Surely its only job is to get the collapse instance. It's absolutely infuriating. Am I doing something wrong? If not, how can I get the collapse instance without toggling it? Obviously in my actual code the setup is more complex than this but this issue is currently holding me up.

There's a fiddle showing the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/philipstratford/43yu8cdt/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `toggle: false` [option](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/collapse/#via-javascript)

The default behavior is

> Toggles the collapsible element on invocation.

```js
const details = document.getElementById("details");
const detailsCollapse = bootstrap.Collapse.getOrCreateInstance(details, {
  toggle: false
})


const btn = document.getElementById("toggleDetails");

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  detailsCollapse.toggle();
});
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="toggleDetails">Show Details</button>
<div class="collapse border mt-2 p-2" id="details">
    Here is some information.
</div>
```

Comment: That's mad default behaviour. I fell foul of the same strange requirement with the default constructor (`bootstrap.Collapse("#myCollapse", { toggle: false })`) but nothing I could see in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/collapse/#methods) suggested that the `getOrCreateInstance` method also accepted an options parameter. Thank you.